# Set pullup from command line

Tags: raspbian, gpio

How do I set the pullup using /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$PIN/value
```

does not seem to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can set the internal pull-up/pull-downs via the sysfs interface.  I have never done so, but I don't often use sysfs.

From the command line there are many methods.  The following examples assume Broadcom gpio 4.

**pigpio**

```
pigs pud 4 u # up
pigs pud 4 d # down
pigs pud 4 o # off
```

**raspi-gpio**

```
raspi-gpio set 4 pu # up
raspi-gpio set 4 pd # down
raspi-gpio set 4 pn # off
```

**wiringPi**

```
gpio -g mode 4 up # up
gpio -g mode 4 down # down
gpio -g mode 4 tri # off
```

Comment: Correct, you can't set the pull-ups or any alt functions via `/sys`.  You can only set the direction and check/set the value.

Comment: I have created a script using `gpio`, which works, but I was hoping there was a method not dependant  on installing other software. There seems to be a dearth of documentation on the `/sys` interface.

Comment: Documentation for the generic kernel GPIO interface in `/sys` is in the vanilla source tree, `[src]/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt` ([also online](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt)).  It's not specific to the pi, which is why it doesn't include stuff like the pull-ups or alt functions.   The people responsible for the rpi kernel *could* have elaborated upon this and created a kernel driver for the pi, but AFAIK they didn't and neither did anyone else -- there is just the various userspace libraries.

Comment: hi @joan, so there is no way to set pull up states using `gpioset` through "libgpiod" ?

Comment: Something like this `gpioset 0 $PIN=1`?